Truncate audio file with FFMPEG without making a copy
I use a RAM disk to edit audios and prefer WAV PCM format for that.
Now I have a large WAV file that takes almost the whole RAM disk (2,5 GB).
Can FFMPEG truncate the file (rebuilding corresponding RIFF structures properly) without writing result to another file?

I think you might want to look into making ffmpeg (and maybe some helper in addition like dd) to read from and write to the same file (but this probably works only if the header being output is of not longer than the original), or just truncate the file with truncate and modify the header (if necessary) with some hex editor whatsoever.

You could possibly get away with it if you are not starting at the beginning.  Otherwise, not a chance.  If it's PCM .wav though, trimming the end off would work, technically.  There's no "necessary" data at the end.


Can FFMPEG truncate the file (rebuilding corresponding RIFF structures properly) without writing result to another file?

No, FFmpeg can't do in-place editing/truncation of files. That is, it can't read and write to the same file.
